# flutter how to make skeleton loader

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this card product card, get it from api with FutureBuilder, when my card is loading i want to show skeleton loader not just `CircularProgressIndicator` , how can i make it.

My futureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
               future: productFuture,
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                 } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                   final catalog = snapshot.data;
                   return buildCatalog(catalog!);
                 } else {
                   return Text("No widget to build");
                 }
               }),
```

here is example of skeleton loader
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this package : [shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer)

```
   Shimmer.fromColors(
      baseColor: Colors.red,
      highlightColor: Colors.yellow,
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The skeletonizer package works very well.
https://pub.dev/packages/skeletonizer

```
Skeletonizer(
  enabled: _loading,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 7,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text('Item number $index as title'),
          subtitle: const Text('Subtitle here'),
          trailing: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```